# Stateful Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, statefulwidget

I am new to flutter and was studying with `StatefulWidget` but I couldn't clearly understand the following term

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget
{
  @override
  _myState createState() => _myState();
}
```

I tried this

`@override
 return _myState();`

And its clear to me, but we user **_myState** before **createState()** method.

Comment: Now that you edited your question, I'm confused what you are trying to ask here. What do you mean by "used _myState before createState() method"?

Comment: I wanted to make it more clear but rather I messed it up. Can you now take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_myState` here is actually a type, not a variable name.

This function here

```
@override
_myState createState() => _myState();
```

is equivalent to:

```
@override
_myState createState() {
    return new _myState();
}
```

where the class `_myState` is likely defined as so:

```
class _myState extends State<MyApp> {
    ...
}
```

In dart, you do not need to use `new` (optional) to instantiate an object.

However by naming convention class names should be in PascalCase, in this case `_MyState` instead of `_myState` which will help make it more readable, especially in your case here.

Comment: one more thing. As far I know, we have types **String, List, Int** etc. But I don't get a clear picture about it **_myState** type

Comment: `_myState createState()` basically means the method `createState()` return a `_myState` type which is defined as a class. Why is it a problem if we "used _myState before createState() method" like you said?

Comment: My question is can we declare any **type** apart from a pre-defined type like **String, Int, List, Bool**.

Comment: You are essentially creating a new type by defining the `_myState` class here. Afterwards you can use the class itself as a type: `_myState newState = new _myState();`

Comment: is there any difference between my newly created type and pre-defined data types?

Comment: Well types are just types. Even primitive data types like String and int are just classes that are defined in the dart libraries.

Comment: (note that `int` and `bool` start with lower case letters)